# How to close areas of this image so I can fill them

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I tried live paint and it won't close the areas. What needs to be done to make this art fillable?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all copy and past in same place then you select the one in the back then go to object>path>offset path> give a number and you have a closed background of that shape u can fill as you like. This process is if u want all the same colour.

Cheers